# linux unable to connec to wifi

Tags: networking

I received a new router, Arris TG862, and now my computer can not connect. I have tried Ubuntu and mint also, so it is not a distro/kernel problem. Also, my computer connects to other secured wi-fii's. While it does connect, I can not visit any sites or ping out.

```
PING 208.67.220.220 (208.67.220.220) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 208.67.220.220 ping statistics --- 3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
```

.

```
[master@EllisHPArch ~]$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232] Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN [8086:1321] Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

.

```
 [master@EllisHPArch ~]$ ping -c 3 8.8.8.8 PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics --- 3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2008ms
```

I have tried multiple topics on this same problem to no avail.

```
    [master@EllisHPArch ~]$ ip address #on wireless
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:63:bb:a7:86:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:d6:86:9c:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.11/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic wlp1s0
       valid_lft 3581sec preferred_lft 3581sec
    inet6 fe80::f925:a355:d4bc:43fa/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

.

```
[master@EllisHPArch ~]$ ip address #while wired
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:63:bb:a7:86:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.16/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 3264sec preferred_lft 3264sec
    inet6 fe80::c001:3a0d:4740:55d9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:d6:86:9c:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.11/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic wlp1s0
       valid_lft 742sec preferred_lft 742sec
    inet6 fe80::c93e:da22:6b49:611d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Since you have internet on other networks, and you can actually connect to yours, i can see of 2 issues. The router itself doesnt have internet access or it has restrictions to your machine, did you tried checking on the router admin interface(1) and testing with another device(2)?

Comment: @bistoco I thought those same things too. A windows or ios product can work on my wi-fi but other linux computers can not. So I tried looking at the router settings and can't find anything I know blocking. Any ideas you have that might be blocking?

Comment: Next thing i will try is to connect over ethernet cable (wifi disabled) and see if it works, to determine if it's the wifi only, or all network connection from linux. Then over wifi ping other machines on the lan, to see if i'm restricted of internet or all network communication.

Comment: @bistoco It has gotten more confusing. I can not ping others or my router and others cannot ping me. It does work over Ethernet. Also other Linux computers can connect and work, yet other distributions on this pc do not work. My driver is up to date. I tried reinstalling networkmanager, wpa _supplicant and dhcp to no avail. I also tried connecting to a WiFi extender on the same network and got similar results. Can connect to extender via cable but not wirelessly. Time Warner was no help but the actually did try

Comment: can you post the ouput of `ifconfig` when connected both by wireless and by cable?

Comment: @bistoco just added it to my original comment. ifconfig is invalid on my current distro. So I changed it to 'ip address'